# Being able to switch between two Page Layouts?

Tags: apex, page-layout, button, pagelayoutassignment

So we have an object in our organization that I recently had to convert a bunch of the fields into another type. I did this by creating new fields and then with APEX, converting the data for each type into the correct data type. Unfortunately, since I was converting from text to currency and (although they SHOULD have been) not every field was just numbers, there are some fields that have missing data.

For this reason, I'm looking for a way to easily transfer between the old page layout (with the text data fields) and the new page layout (with the currency fields). This way, if we notice there is some data missing due to an inaccuracy in input before, we can easily look to see what the input should be and input it ourselves.

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way for a user to quickly switch page layouts, but if I were in this situation I would use Data Loader to export all the problematic records, remove the non-numeric content with formulae in Excel, and then import the clean values back into the new fields.

Comment: This is important to from a backup perspective.  Converting a datatype against the object can irreparably effect your data, so extracting, converting, and reloading the field values is always the correct process.

Comment: All the old data is still there, and I used an APEX method to take out the non-numeric numbers when I could, but some of them are so problematic that it would take going through by hand to fix it (i.e. prices and notes for three items in a field that is only supposed to have the price for one item). I'm not changing any of the fields that I have right now, simply creating new ones that I've replaced on the layout so that I can add, subtract, multiply and such with them. I just want to make it easy for my coworkers to be able to view what WAS in the spot if there's a case like I mentioned above

Comment: In that case, I agree with Matt's idea below, to just put both fields next to each other on the layout, or maybe put the old one out of the way, lower down the page so that it's available for reference in those odd circumstances, but not getting in anyone's way or confusing people between the two fields.  

You may also want to go into your field-level security settings and make the old field read-only for most users (i.e. non-admins).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dupe_Jockey and HomerJ that exporting, cleaning, and reloading is the best way to do this. However, since it seems that you have already transferred the data to new fields, I would suggest creating a new page layout (perhaps restricted to admins) that shows both values side by side.

Or, you could just export to Excel/DemandTools and do all the cleaning en masse.